# How to get the average interval from a single datetime column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in my mysql database.

```
user_id| department | comment_time
-----------------------------------------
ahnaf  |     OM1    | 2018-02-01 10:00:00
muttaki|     OM2    | 2018-02-01 11:00:00
sunny  |     OM3    | 2018-02-01 12:00:00
ahnaf  |     OM1    | 2018-02-01 21:00:00
john   |     OM2    | 2018-02-01 23:00:00
```

From this table i want to find out how often someone from a department comments.
I am looking for an answer like: A person from OM1 comments every 5 minutes on average.

I have no idea how to write a query for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the average spacing between comments by taking the total span and dividing by one less than the number of comments:

```
select department,
       ( ( to_seconds(max(comment_time)) - to_seconds(min(comment_time))
         ) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
       ) / 60 as avg_comment_in_minutes
from t
group by department;
```

If you know that the comments are up-to-date and you want to handle the span since most recent comment, then you can do:

```
select department,
       ( ( to_seconds(now()) - to_seconds(min(comment_time))
         ) / count(*)
       ) / 60 as avg_comment_in_minutes
from t
group by department;
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
SELECT user_id,department, FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(comment_time))) as average_time 
FROM dept 
GROUP by user_id
```

i'm using table name as dept

Answer (score 0):

try this

`select department,
avg(diff_comment_time) FROM 
(select department,
LAG(comment_time) OVER ( PARTITION BY department ORDER BY comment_time DESC) - comment_time as diff_comment_time
from test) test2
group by department`